# On next page or previous page button click request goes to server but for radio button this maintain previous button value in crystal report

Tags: c#, angularjs, webforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have multiple **radio buttons** when I open these radio button reports in different tabs and after that I comes to any random tab report and click on next page button or previous page button it renders the last open tab's reports data. It is due to reason it goes to server side ReportViewer.aspx.cs and at there I had created switch case on the bases of radio buttons and that code maintains last value of radio button which opened in last tab. So here I'm stuck how to refresh the radio button value on tab change, It should detect now which radio button reports request came. Below Image shows the radio buttons and *code* also given below

```
    if (reportFilterParams != null)
                        {
                            if (reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName == PurchaseSheetChildReport.PurcaseDepotReceievedSheet)
                            {
                                errorMessage.Text = "Report Not Found";
                            }
                            else if (reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName == PurchaseSheetChildReport.PurcaseSummaryCircleAndGrowerWise)
                            {
                                errorMessage.Text = "Report Not Found";
                            }
                            else if (reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName == PurchaseSheetChildReport.PurcaseSummaryCircleAndGrowerWiseDetail)
                            {
                                reportPath = Server.MapPath("../../Reports/Grower/PurchaseSummaryCricleAndGrowerWiseDetail.rpt");
                                ReportDocument.Load(reportPath);
                                ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["ReportName"].Text = "'Purchase Summary Circle And Grower Wise Detail'";
                                PurchaseSheetSummaryCPWiseAndCenterWise();
                            }
}
```

[Image for radio button display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tMu2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in this way, I just set the tab title with radio button value on client side when give submit call and get the current tab's value via c# code that is given below and then make session with each radio button when click on next or previous page button it goes to the server with tab value and get the session value with the tab title value.

[Set title with radio button value in browser tab see in image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YOpT.jpg

```
//client side code in javascript
            if (reportValueForName != undefined)
                window.document.title = $("input:checked + label").text() + "_" + reportValueForName;
            else
                window.document.title = $("#reportNameMaster").text() + " Report";

 //Server side code
    string curentTabReportName = GetTabTitle();
    
                string resultString = Regex.Match(curentTabReportName, @"\d+").Value;
    
                if (resultString != "")
                {
                    reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName = Convert.ToInt32(resultString);
                }

   
    public string GetTabTitle()
            {
                string currentReportTabTitle = "";
                Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
                    {
                        //the chrome process must have a window
                        if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
    
                        currentReportTabTitle = proc.MainWindowTitle;
                    }
                }
    
                return currentReportTabTitle;
            }

    //Set the session value

   

     Session["reportFilterParams" + reportFilterModel.UserName + reportFilterModel.MenueId + reportFilterModel.SelectedReportName] = reportFilterModel;

    //Get the session value


    if (Session["reportFilterParams" + Session["UserName"] + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"] + reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName)] as ReportFilterModel != null)
                {
                    reportFilterParams = Session["reportFilterParams" + Session["UserName"] + int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"] + reportFilterParams.SelectedReportName)] as ReportFilterModel;
                }
```